# Sequence number in xslt for Nested tags in a loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to generate sequence number for below xml in the output text file along with some tag data.
INPUT XML:

```
<OS>
     <Android>
        <codeName>Kitkat</codeName>
        <version>
           <build>123</build>
           <build>456</build>
           <build>789</build>
        </version>
        <version>
           <build>321</build>
        </version>
     </Android>
     <Android>
        <codeName>lollipop</codeName>
        <version>
           <build>654</build>
        </version>
     </Android>
</OS>
<OS>
     <Android>
        <codeName>Jelly bean</codeName>
     </Android>
     <Android>
        <codeName>Marshmallow</codeName>
        <version>
           <build>879</build>
        </version>
        <version>
           <build>312</build>
           <build>645</build>
        </version>
     </Android>
</OS>
```

Expected output:

```
kitkat      1 000
build       2 123
build       3 456
build       4 789
version     5 000
build       6 321
version     7 000
lollipop    8 000
build       9 654
version    10 000
static1    11 000
static2    12 000
Jelly bean 13 000
Marshmallow14 000
build      15 879
version    16 000
build      17 312
build      18 645
version    19 000
static1    20 000
static2    21 000
```

What i have tried so far:

```
<xsl:template match="OS/Android">
   <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()+(2*count(preceding::OS))+2*count(preceding::Android/version)+2*count(preceding::Android/version/build)"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="codeName"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
   <xsl:text>000</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#xa</xsl:text>
   <xsl:for-each select="version">
      <xsl:for-each select="build">
         <xsl:text>build</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="build"/>
         <xsl:text>&#xa</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:text>version</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
         <xsl:text>000</xsl:text>
         <xsl:text>&#xa</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="OS/Android[last()]">
   <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()+(2*count(preceding::OS))+2*count(preceding::Android/version)+2*count(preceding::Android/version/build)"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="codeName"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
   <xsl:text>000</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#xa</xsl:text>
   <xsl:for-each select="version">
      <xsl:for-each select="build">
         <xsl:text>build</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="build"/>
         <xsl:text>&#xa</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:text>version</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
         <xsl:text>000</xsl:text>
         <xsl:text>&#xa</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:text>static1</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
   <xsl:text>000</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#xa</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>static2</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
   <xsl:text>000</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#xa</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>
```

Problem is **I'm not able to generate correct sequence number(pos)** in output. Please help me in acheiving this logic.

Points to note:
-First line always contain codeName
-from Second line builds in a version
-next line contains version
-last Android tag occurence contains 2 static lines at end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it would be more convenient to do this in two passes:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="nodes">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="OS"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$nodes/node">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<!-- first pass templates: -->

<xsl:template match="OS">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Android"/>
    <node name="static1" value="000"/>
    <node name="static1" value="000"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Android">
    <node name="{codeName}" value="000"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="version"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="version">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="build"/>
    <node name="version" value="000"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="build">
    <node name="build" value="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to a **well-formed input**  (i.e. after adding a root element to your example), the result will be:

```
Kitkat  1   000
build   2   123
build   3   456
build   4   789
version 5   000
build   6   321
version 7   000
lollipop    8   000
build   9   654
version 10  000
static1 11  000
static1 12  000
Jelly bean  13  000
Marshmallow 14  000
build   15  879
version 16  000
build   17  312
build   18  645
version 19  000
static1 20  000
static1 21  000
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, I've applied it to my xml but output file is empty. In my actual xsl i'm using call-template(displays actual data) and storing it in a variable(templateData) and using it in node value attribute.eg: <node name="$someData" value="$templateData"/>. can i use it like this?

Comment: @Jarvis I cannot see your modified code so I cannot tell you what's wrong with it. I don't see why it's necessary to modify it that way either.

Comment: in my actual xml i've got multiple tags to display so i prepared template to display values. so i'm calling template and storing values in node >value attribute. how can i store that variable in this node?

Comment: @Jarvis I am afraid I don't know what you mean. The above works with the example you have posted (after adding a root element). If you cannot get it to work with your actual XML, then either edit your question and show us what it really looks like, or post a new question.

Comment: Thanks to you, I managed to get the solution for my actual xml.